# Select Max with groupby

Tags: sql, sql-server

> I have the following table.

[image]

I need to select SemesterID,AcadamiYear,AcademicSemester of the record with highest Academic year and Academic semester of the year 2015

Expected output is

> 2013 1 2

I tried the following query but it returns both of the records

```
select MAX(AcadamiYear) as Year,
  MAX(AcadamicSemester) as Semester
  ,SemesterID
  from
  tblSemesterRegistration 
  where [IntakeYear]='2015'
  Group by SemesterID
```

Comment: I think there is wrong entry in the table - like - **AcadamiYear** should be **2012** or **2013** and **SemesterID** should be like - 1, 2 and all... Am i right ???

Comment: @KrishnrajRana no. SemesterID is the primary key column (auto increment)

Comment: shall you group by IntakeYear instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are searching for a single record you might use TOP 1, ordered by your intend

```
select TOP 1 *
  from
  tblSemesterRegistration 
  where [IntakeYear]='2015'
  Order by AcadamiYear DESC, AcadamicSemester DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT SR.*
FROM tblSemesterRegistration SR
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(SR2.AcadamiYear) AS [AcadamiYear]
                  ,MAX(SR2.AcadamicSemester) AS [AcadamicSemester]
                  ,IntakeYear
            FROM tblSemesterRegistration SR2
            GROUP BY SR2.IntageYear) T ON T.AcadamiYear = SR.AcadamiYear
                                         AND T.AcadamicSemester = SR.AcadamicSemester
                                         AND T.IntakeYear = SR.IntakeYear
WHERE SR.IntakeYear = '2015'
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(AcadamiYear) AS Year,
    MAX(AcademicSemester) AS Semester,
    MAX(SemesterID) AS SemesterID
FROM tblSemesterRegistration 
WHERE [IntakeYear] = '2015'
GROUP BY IntakeYear
```

Answer (score 0):

If `SemesterID` is the primary key, grouping on it will always yield all rows (since it is always unique).

I guess you mean to find back that semester id with the parameters set:

```
select r.*
from   tblSemesterRegistration r
join   ( select max(AcadamiYear) as Year
         ,      max(AcadamicSemester) as Semester
         from   tblSemesterRegistration 
         where  [IntakeYear]='2015'
       ) m
on     r.acadamiyear = m.year
and    r.acadamicsemester = m.semester
```